# $B$ is submatrix of $A$ and rankA=rankB then $x>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   x & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & y & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & z & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & t  \\
\end{array}} \right)$ and $B = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   x & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & y & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & z  \\
\end{array}} \right)$ and $Rank(A)=Rank(B)$ , and $y,z,t \ge 0$

Can we prove that $x>0$?

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider the matrices

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} B =\begin{pmatrix}  -1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 1 &0 \\  0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix}$$

The two matrices satisfy the constraints

(A) $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(B)$

(B) $y,z,t\geq0$

You can immediately verify that $x<0$, falsifying the claim.

**Edit: what happens if $\det(B)\geq0$?**

The claim does not hold even if we require $\det(B)$ to be non-negative. Consider

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} B =\begin{pmatrix}  -1 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 &0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: "You can immediately verify that $x<0$" ,why?

Comment: Because x=-1!@KD-tel

Comment: ,Dear, if  $\det B \ge 0$, Is this question true?

Comment: @KD-tel I've updated my answer!